# How to save image in hive DB picked by user using ImagePicker?

Tags: image, file-upload, hive, flutter-hive, flutter-image-picker

As i implemented my own way to put image in hive but it did not work. I searched on internet but not found any sound solution. A complete code to implement it can be helpful. Any help will be appreciated. Thanks!

Code i used to pick image and put it into hive.

```
  File? _image;
    Future getAndSaveImage() async {
      final image = await ImagePicker().pickImage(source: ImageSource.gallery);
if (image == null) return;
final tempImage = File(image.path);
setState(() {
  _image = tempImage;
  images.put(_nameController.text, ProfileImage(_image!));
});
    }
```

Hive Model Class

```
import 'dart:io';

import 'package:hive/hive.dart';

part 'profile_image.g.dart';

@HiveType(typeId: 2)
class ProfileImage {
  ProfileImage(this.profileStudentImage);
  @HiveField(0)
  final File profileStudentImage;
}
```

Please give a proper working solution i really need it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You first need to convert the image to a format that can be stored in Hive, typically a Uint8List (byte array). Then, you can save this byte array in a Hive box

Before saving an image to Hive, you need to convert it into a Uint8List. You can use the ImagePicker package to select an image and convert it to bytes.

```
PickedFile pickedFile = await ImagePicker().getImage(source: ImageSource.gallery);
List<int> imageBytes = await pickedFile.readAsBytes();
Uint8List imageUint8List = Uint8List.fromList(imageBytes);
```

Save Image to Hive:

Once you have the image in Uint8List format, you can save it to Hive:

```
Box imageBox = Hive.box('images'); // Open the 'images' box

// Save the Uint8List to Hive
imageBox.put('image_key', imageUint8List);
```

Retrieve Image from Hive:

```
Box imageBox = Hive.box('images'); // Open the 'images' box

// Get the Uint8List from Hive
Uint8List retrievedImage = imageBox.get('image_key');
```

Display Image:

```
Image.memory(retrievedImage);
```

Comment: Though the modal class was not defining Unit8List despite importing the typed package, I declared the variable as dynamic and it worked perfectly fine.
Thanks a lot, man!